# What do X-headers in mails stand for?

Tags: email, email-headers

I'm wondering what all `X-` headers in e-mails stand for.

- Are they really just a custom and everyone can make them up?
- Are they documented somewhere? I've quickly browsed [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). It does not seem to mention anything about custom headers.
- When or by whom were they introduced?

Thank you for shedding some light in that field :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) ("Standard for the Format of ARPA Internet Text Messages") specified in sections 4.7.4 and 4.7.5 that headers beginning with "X-" would not ever be part of any standard, and thus can be used for application-specific purposes.

For what it's worth, the more recent BCP document [RFC6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) ("Deprecating the 'X-' Prefix and Similar Constructs in Application Protocols") recommends that the use of the "X-" prefix be avoided in the future, as the distinction between standardized and nonstandardized headers is not well defined, and attempting to draw such a distinction fails when commonly used nonstandard headers are adopted as standards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Especially the pointer tot he second document talks a little bit about the history.

Comment: I've noticed that these headers are dropped when forwarded. Is there a way to have headers persist when forwarding email ?